# Serving root-level static files on Heroku with Django?

Tags: django, heroku, favicon

I need to serve several root-level static files on Heroku (eg, `domain.com/favicon.ico`). Here's the list of files as it currently stands:

```
favicon.ico
crossdomain.xml
sitemap.xml
robots.txt
humans.txt
apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon.png
```

I've searched high and low and can't find a standard way to serve a large set of static files. Wherever I host them (on Heroku with collectstatic or Amazon S3), explicitly defining and redirecting 14 files in my urls.py seems incorrect.

Comment: So what you main problem: you cant load files to heroku/S3 or set correct url to this resources?

Comment: @b1-Setting correct URL.

Comment: try this manuals [blog1](http://matthewphiong.com/managing-django-static-files-on-heroku) [blog2](http://www.iknuth.com/2011/10/deploying-a-django-app-to-heroku-with-easy-static-files-on-s3/). Be ware I think it are for django 1.3. If it dont help post you `settings.py`.

Comment: Those are both nice resources, but the issue is that I want to serve static files at the root level (domain.com/favicon.ico), and I don't want to use Django's static view (it's not meant to be used in production).

Comment: Hi knite. I've come across your excellent question here while trying to figure out a [related one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447314/handling-all-website-one-off-root-static-files-like-favicon-ico-reliably-and-ele). Sorry to see no answer for this yet. Did you ever find another way?

Comment: @Ghopper21 I included a list of files on this question in the hopes that someone would call out either missing or extraneous files. That's the set of static content I believe is necessary. To prevent errors in your log, have you considered using a catch-all pattern in your urls.py?

Answer (score 4):

This is my current solution. Feedback appreciated.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from settings import STATIC_URL, ASSETS, DEBUG, AWS_STORAGE

#ASSETS is a tuple: ('favicon.ico, 'robots.txt', ...)    
urls = [('^%s$' % f, 'redirect_to', {'url': STATIC_URL + f}) for f in ASSETS]
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple', *urls)

#Serve static files from runserver if in dev mode with S3 off.
if DEBUG and not AWS_STORAGE:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: Given that I probably won't have many root assets, I think this solution is fine enough.

Answer (score 2):

Despite this is being an old question, I still have the problem. I like the way the URLs are generated from a list in the current solution, but I was not convinced that was the best.

After a bit of research though, I found [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) being a very useful resources which generates all the required favicons files for you and I was sent [this post](http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/failproof-favicons/) by a colleague which seems to support the proposed solution, with a more recent Django version.

Based on all the above, my solution is using native sitemap framework, [django-robots](https://github.com/jezdez/django-robots) for robots.txt and a ROOT_ASSETS dictionary, with files prefix as key, and values as a list of files, for example:

```
ROOT_ASSETS = {
    "images/favicons/": [
        "apple-touch-icon-114x114.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-120x120.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-144x144.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-180x180.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-57x57.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-60x60.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-72x72.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-76x76.png",
        "apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png",
        "favicon.ico",
    ]
}
```

Then I generate my urls with:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

root_assets_urls = []
for prefix, files in ROOT_ASSETS.iteritems():
    for f in files:
        asset_url = staticfiles_storage.url("{prefix}{file}".format(prefix=prefix, file=f))
        root_assets_urls.append(
            url(r'^{0}$'.format(f), RedirectView.as_view(url=asset_url))
        )
root_assets = patterns('', *root_assets_urls)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include(root_assets)),
    [...]
)
```

I'm also including the HTML generated by [realfavicongenerator.net](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) in my master template's head.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any url config files, so I think heroku not provide this service.

And according to [official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) you need save your data on external services

EDIT:

So according to heroku docs only 301 redirects to S3 can help you. Or even better for all media (ico, favicons, png and another images) files in templates set absolute path to S3 services and for robots and crossdomain.xml in `urls.py` set 301 redirects to S3. For sitemap.xml better use [native solutions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/)

It is not wrong to use right redirects codes in development.

Comment: My question states that I am using an external service (Amazon S3). I am asking about the best way to serve the files (eg, urls.py).

Comment: I just edit my answer. Do you need code or abstract solution fine too? ;)