# Handling all website one-off root static files like favicon.ico reliably and elegantly?

Tags: ios, django, heroku, web, gunicorn

Perhaps I'm missing something (I hope I am!), but it seems awfully clunky to have to have deal with the one-off root website files requested by the browser, such as favicon.ico and things like apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png (on the iPad). Right now, I'm getting a 500 server error whenever I encounter one of these for which I'm not explicitly serving up a file.

My questions:

1. Is there an up-to-date list of all such files for all major browsers that my webapp should be handling?
2. As a failsafe, is there way for the absence of any of these files to fail silently, i.e. to NOT get a 500 server error with the webapp continuing on its merry way, simply using a blank favicon or whatever?

I'm running a Django app on Heroku with gunicorn.

Comment: you might want to give us details for your 500 (run in debug mode, or get the logs). It should give you a 400, not a 500, so something is wrong in your configuration!

Answer (score 1):

I never get a 500 error from invalid urls, because I use STATIC_URL and the class based RedirectView

Usually I have an app dedicated to this, and include it in the root urls.py with

```
#urls.py
include('oneoff.urls', name='oneoff')`
```

and

```
#oneoff/urls.py
urlpatterns = ( '',
    url(r'favicon.ico$',
        RedirectView.as_view(url=urlparse.urljoin(settings.STATIC_URL, "img/favicon.ico")),
        name="favicon"
    ),
    url(r'icon-precomposed.png',
        RedirectView.as_view(url=urlparse.urljoin(settings.STATIC_URL, "img/iphone/icon.png")),
        name="iphone"
    ),
)
```

then in the template

```
{% load url from future %}
<link rel="favicon" href="{% url 'oneoff:favicon' %} />
```

Comment: Nice, but wouldn't this 500 for, say, `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`? I'm looking for a failsafe catch-all.