# Nginx - Forward root-level URL (eg, favicon.ico) to Amazon S3?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, config

I'm trying to configure my nginx server to serve root level assets, like `www.domain.com/favicon.ico`, from S3.

I think, but am not sure, that I'm supposed to proxy_pass to accomplish this. I'm also stuck on the location regex:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name *.domain.com

    # This is where I'm trying to catch URLs like /favicon.ico
    location ~* /*\.(xml|txt|png|ico)$ {    # wrong
        proxy_pass http://<s3_bucket>??     # wrong
    }

    # Everything else goes to gunicorn/Django.
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

}

Comment: So just a small question, wouldn't using nginx as a proxy defeat the purpose of using s3, people use s3 to remove the bandwidth consumption from the server, and by using nginx as a proxy you're actually doubling it not removing it ( s3 -> nginx -> user ), why not let the app output the actual s3 URL and the browser will handle the rest ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady That's a fair question. I do as you suggest when referencing these resources on pages generated by my app. However, these resources (favicon.ico, apple-touch*, robots.txt, sitemap.xml, etc) are often accessed directly.

Django is not designed to serve static files in production, so my only option would be redirecting those requests to S3. In fact, here's a question I posted last year asking about how to do exactly that on Heroku - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589169/serving-root-level-static-files-on-heroku-with-django

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady (continued)

I'm working on a different project running on real servers. In this case, as far as I know, I can and should serve those static files via nginx.

Comment: wouldn't it be cheaper then to actually serve them from the server instead of proxying s3? and put a rule to exclude them from the proxy to django

Answer (score 0):

It's right to do this using proxy_pass. If you have problem you can set error log to debug level to trace the problem. From the trace log, you should focus on two points:

1. Whether `/*\.(xml|txt|png|ico)$` match your requests?
2. Whether the url being passed is right and access successfully?